# PHP: Making this grabbing from db easier/simpler way?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any method i could do this easier:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id = '$show[uID]'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row["full_name"] . " ";
```

as i only need to grab the full_name, then i make a var for the fetch_array and so, is there any way to make this simpler and echo? There was something about list(), but im not sure..

Comment: Just use a MVC framework it will make your life easier )  
P.S. Do not down vote the newbies lack of knowledge is not bad, it is bad when you do not want to learn

Comment: Most(if not all) MVC frameworks provide abstract layer between the application and the database in a way that you work with your data as it is a object and do not write SQL queries(except for very special things).

Comment: Recommending a full-blown MVC framework as a solution to a simple question is not a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring possible security breaches and the usefulness of a DAL (see @deceze's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715683/php-making-this-grabbing-from-db-easier-simpler-way/3715738#3715738)), I recommend the use of [**`mysql_result()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` (or *_array() or whatever):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id = '$show[uID]'");
$fullName = mysql_result($query, 0);
echo $fullName . " ";
```

Not easier *per se* but should be more in line with the intention of the query (fetch *one* field in *one* row).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to *abstract* this any more and thereby make the actual call shorter is by using a [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer) and/or [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/), which you should anyway.

Comment: +1 for genuine abstraction, not just (more or less) generalized helper methods.

Comment: @jensgram as a matter of fact, Doctrine has very similar helpers.

Answer (score 0):

May be not easier, but more securely:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($show['uID']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `full_name` FROM `users` WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['full_name'];
```

Oh you can to make id with intval:

```
$id = intval($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could make further DB-questions easier;

```
function mysql_fetch_scalar($res)
{
    $arr = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    return $arr[0];
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id = '".intval($show[uID])."'");
$fullname = mysql_fetch_scalar($query);
echo $fullname . " ";
```

Comment: 1. Thought it would be easier with a function that returned the value of the first field 2. Yes, I saw that after I posted, I fixed the code aswell.

Comment: That's easy enough to not warrant abstraction into a super specialized function IMHO. You could make it a one-liner with `current(mysql_fetch_array())` if you insist. Removed the -1 though, since at least the code works now.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.
Moreover, you should - to make a function out of these repetitive API functions calls.
Something as simple, as this

```
function dbgetvar($query){
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return FALSE;
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
  if (!$row) return "";
  return $row[0];
}
```

have this function in your config file and use every time you want a value from database:

```
echo dbgetval("SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id = '$show[uID]'");
```

(I hope you have $show[uID] escaped)

Of course there can be also 2 similar functions, to return a row or a rowset. Or just one but with additional parameter. Or you can combine them into class...

You can make it even escape variables for you:

```
function dbgetvar(){
  $args = func_get_args();
  $query = array_shift($args);
  foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
    $args[$key] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."'";
  }
  $query = vsprintf($query, $args);
  if (!$query) return false;

  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return FALSE;
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
  if (!$row) return "";
  return $row[0];
}

echo dbgetvar("SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id = %s",$show['uID']);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what you have to do.  You could wrap that in a helper function if you're using it a fair bit, but then you'd probably want to cache the answer you get - I don't suppose the name changes all that often...

```
function echoName($user_id) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $row["full_name"] . " ";
}

// ...

echoName($show['uID']);
```